# Question regarding "vor"

Tags: grammar, preposition

I recently came across this sentence

> Die Delfine haben ihn umzingelt, aber nicht vor, ihn zu fressen.

(The *ihn* here refers to a small fish.)

How does the meaning of that sentence differ from

> Die Delfine haben ihn umzingelt, aber nicht, **um** ihn zu fressen.

?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your sentence seems to be meant as a shortened version of

> Die Delfine haben ihn umzingelt, aber *sie haben* nicht vor, ihn zu fressen.

The repeated verb *haben* has been omitted. This is a common practice in general, but here it is bad style, because the first *haben* is an auxiliary verb, while the second *haben* is a full verb, moreover: it is only a part of the verb [*vorhaben*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vorhaben) that is actually being used here. So it is rather the same character sequence for two different verbs, and this shouldn't be shortened (except for an intended comic effect).

The difference to

> Die Delfine haben ihn umzingelt, aber nicht, um ihn zu fressen.

is that the former talks about two separate (though probably related) actions (*umzingeln* and *vorhaben zu fressen*), while the latter explicitly negates that one action is the purpose of the other (that's what the *um* brings about).